# How do I log all my internet-connections

Tags: logging, proxy

How can I (maybe with a proxy, but I need names of programs!?) log all my interactions of programs with my Internet connection, so that I could see WHAT a program is sending and WHAT it is receiving. (For example a program receives an XML Doc and I would like to read it.)

Also it would be very useful if I could modify every connection. For example programs trying to connect with: anyserver.amznsrv.com:4599, and I would like to redirect it to `localhost` or something like that.

Comment: when you specify `anyserver.amznsrv.com:4599`, do you want to redirect only port 4599, or any connection to that server?  And what OS are you using?

Answer (score 10):

For tracking what is sent and received, you can use a packet sniffer. I use Wireshark (formerly Ethereal).

Answer (score 8):

*If* you're dealing with HTTP (and/or HTTPS) on Windows, [Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fiddler/info) might help you there:

- it hooks into Winsock, so it can tell you the program name
- it will show you all HTTP(s) requests and responses passing through it
- and it allows you to modify those, either manually or through scripts

Comment: Can a program bypass Fiddler by working *below* it?

Comment: @Pacerier: Sure.

Answer (score 7):

Adding to @Piskvor answer - if you need to look at HTTP layer, you should be looking for a intercepting HTTP(s) proxy. There are several such proxies available, both free and commercial ones. If you're on Windows, Fiddler is a good choice. On other platforms you could try:

- [Burp proxy](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html)
- [OWASP ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project)
- [OWASP WebScarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project)

All of them will probably be right for the task you specified.

Comment: Can one of them modify the packets and resend them?

Comment: not really packets, these tools work in HTTP layer, so you can modify HTTP requests / responses. But yes, these tools are designed specifically for that purpose to be used by web application penetration testers.