# Monitor data a program sends to internet

Tags: sniffer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i log all my internet-connections](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8898/how-do-i-log-all-my-internet-connections)

I have a program that connects to the Internet, this program apparently is sending out my mac address and computer information to a server but I am not entirely sure. The program is not a virus or a trojan, it's actually a tool for a game.

Is there any tool that tracks the data that this program is sending to the Internet or receiving? like a sniffer tool or something?

Answer (score 3):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), packet analyzer, it's really low level but has tons of tools for helping you read what a packet contains. You can use it to "follow" a TCP connection, so you can see all data being sent back and forth.

Comment: This tool's data seems to be hidden cant be seen in the packets. can anyone care to try, p r o j e c t-i n t e r c e p t . c o m

Comment: If the data it is sending is encoded or encrypted, then there might not be any way to see the data being sent. But it there was, Wireshark IS the way to capture the data that you can try to decode/decrypt.

Comment: The data also may not be in ASCII/UTF, so you'll likely be reading it in a hex editor and trying to reverse engineer it.